# CheckboxToogle ExtJS4

Tags: checkbox, extjs4, fieldset

i have a fieldset with checkboxToggle in Extjs 4:

```
{
   anchor: '100%',
   xtype: 'container',
   layout: 'column',
   items: [{
     id: 'fieldsetNuovaTecnologia',
     columnWidth: .50,
     xtype: 'fieldset',
     title: 'Definisci Nuova Tecnologia',
     checkboxToggle: true,
     collapsed: true,// mantiene di default chiuso il fildset
     checkboxName: 'checkboxNuovaTecnologia', 
     items:[{....
```

How do I verify if it is checked or unchecked?

I tried with:

1) Ext.getCmp('checkboxNuovaTecnologia').getValue();

2) Ext.get('fieldsetNuovaTecnologia').dom.checked;

but don't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
var fieldsetCheckbox = Ext.getCmp('fieldsetNuovaTecnologia').checkboxCmp;
var isChecked = fieldsetCheckbox.getValue(); // isChecked = true or false
```